# CONTRACT RESPECTING FINANCIAL SELF-SUFFICIENCY - Quebec province

Tags: france, immigration, canadian-citizens, french-citizens

Document [checklist](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/publications/en/dcs/documents-dcs-en-dyn.pdf) for quebec asks for below contract form, which is not avaialable

### [image]

In this [link](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/forms/search-title/dcs-workers/index.html), we have a [page](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/forms/search-title/caf.html) for financial contract for Quebec immigration(as skilled worker) where the form is [available](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/publications/fr/dcs/A-0522-OF-dyn.pdf) in French language for year 2015.

```
CAF – Travailleurs qualifiés, entrepreneurs et travailleurs autonomes (Dynamic PDF, 838 Ko)
(FSC – Skilled Worker, Entrepreneur and Self-Employed Person) 
(English version to come)
```

This is the english [version](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/publications/en/dcs/A-0522-OA.pdf) of contract for last year(2014).

Checklist document demands for `A-0522-OA` contract form where as french contract form is `A-0522-OF`

Can I submit this french version contract form instead of waiting for English version?

Comment: The site you linked to seems to indicate "yes", for the reasons that you already put in your question. Could you please be more clear as to why you think it might *not* be acceptable? For example, is the rest of your application in English, or have you read somewhere that certain forms must be in English? This *is* Quebec we're talking about. It would be surprising if an official form was not allowed to be in the official language.

Comment: @DanGetz Query edited. I think your question: "is the rest of your application in English?"  is answered

Comment: Why -1 for this question?

Comment: The checklist you linked to states the contract is necessary. It links to that official document in French. I don't see how "Am I allowed I submit this official document that they told me to submit?" is a reasonable question, sorry.

Comment: @DanGetz Above check list says about contract document "A-0522-OA" where as french contract form is "A-0522-OF"

Comment: alright I understand. I removed my downvote, though I still feel the answer should be an obvious "yes" from the links that you already read and put into your question.

Comment: @DanGetz Yes? If I fill up "A-0522-OF" form, How can I check the entry for "A-0522-OA" in document check list?

Comment: @mkennedy Do you think you can help me on this? This is an urgent query

Comment: My close vote is based on the feedback in comments... the OP has already answered his own question, as users point out this... as such, it becomes unclear/unanswerable.